# Timepicker React component

Tags: html, datetime, react.js, jsx

I have developed a simple timepicker component. I did this only for learning and getting more familiar with reactjs. The feature this timepicker will have

a) Select time in AM and PM

b) Convert am/pm to 24 hour format

c) Final value will be needed in both 24 hour format and 12 hour format

Regarding the feature **b**, I doubt my code is good enough. The way I implemented it might create many bugs. I am skeptical about it, as I am not confident enough. Can anyone help me to refactor this code, please? I want to know how a better programmer will handle such conditions without bugs on the feature that has been implemented covering the required conditions.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import "./time.css";

class TimePicker extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: "9",
      hourTime: "9:30",
      selectedNumber: 1,
      meridian: "AM",
      minutes: "30",
      hasError: false
    };
  }

  handleClick(time) {
    const { meridian, minutes } = this.state;
    const hourTime = moment(`${time}:${minutes} ${meridian}`, [
      "h:mm A"
    ]).format("HH:mm");
    this.setState({
      time,
      selectedNumber: time,
      hourTime
    });
  }

  handleTimeAmPm(meridian) {
    const { time, minutes } = this.state;
    const hourTime = moment(`${time}:${minutes} ${meridian}`, [
      "h:mm A"
    ]).format("HH:mm");
    this.setState({ meridian, hourTime });
  }

  handleMinutes = e => {
    const { value, min, max } = e.target;
    if (value >= min && value < max) {
      const hourTime = moment(
        `${this.state.time}:${value} ${this.state.meridian}`,
        ["h:mm A"]
      ).format("HH:mm");
      if (value.length < 2) {
        this.setState({ minutes: "0" + value.slice(-2), hourTime });
      } else {
        this.setState({ minutes: value.slice(-2), hourTime });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({ minutes: "00", hasError: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    let time = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      time.push(
        <div
          className={this.state.selectedNumber === i ? "hand selected" : "hand"}
          key={i}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
        >
          {i}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="card card-md" style={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <div className="time-date">
          <div className="display">
            <div className="content">
              <div className="main-title">
                {this.state.time}:{this.state.minutes}
                <small> {this.state.meridian}</small>
              </div>
              <div className="sub-title">
                {this.state.hourTime}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="control">
            <div className="slider">
              <div className="time-control">
                <div className="clock">
                  <div className="clock-face">
                    <div className="center" />
                    {time}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="actions">
                  <div className="am" onClick={() => this.handleTimeAmPm("AM")}>
                    AM
                  </div>
                  <div className="minutes">
                    <div className={this.state.hasError && "input error"}>
                      <input
                        type="number"
                        min={0}
                        max={60}
                        value={this.state.minutes}
                        onChange={this.handleMinutes}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="pm" onClick={() => this.handleTimeAmPm("PM")}>
                    PM
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TimePicker;
```

Here is the demo to see in action:

https://codesandbox.io/s/9zx70rvk4p